# How to change default "Categories" and "Sources" in Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

So I have started using the Dash recently.

What I want is to set the default "Categories" (Applications, Social, Weather...) because now, if I want to search for a FB pic or an update, I have to manually click on "Social" on the right side of the Dash. Right now, depending on my search, either Applications, Weather or Reference show automatically, but not Social for example.

I want to manually set the default "Categories" I want the Dash to use when I search for something without the need of clicking on the right side.

The same thing happens with the "Sources", under "Categories". I want Wikipedia, Facebook and some others to appear by default but I have to search through all of the sources list and manually click on them, which takes some time.

So, is there a **way to choose the default Categories and Sources for the Dash**?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Open dash, search for `dconf`.

Open `dconf-editor`, go to com > canonical > Unity > Lenses.

Open dash again, select the lenses you want to search by default. In `dconf-editor`, Copy the key value from `home-lens-default-view` and paste it in the key named `always-search`.

PS: You have to have `dconf-editor` installed. To install it run:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks for your help. I can finally use the dash as I wanted.

Comment: Thanks. It is ridiculous that such an obviously desired customization requires installation of tool. Such options should be clearly visibly and available within the dash itself. Each dash menu should have an "options" button capable of providing a wide range of customizations for that which is on that same screen. Duh!

Comment: These instructions don't make any sense. What is dash? A command line program? Don't think so, that's a shell. How do you "search" the dashboard if it is just a bunch of icons? Agree with Lonnie, it's absurd how non-trivial this is.

Comment: @charlesreid1 Dash is the launcher you get when you press the `<super>` key.