# Ubuntu calculator in dash

Tags: unity-dash, calculator

I want to install the calculator in `Dash` in Ubuntu 14.04, I installed `unity-scope-calculator`, but still nothing, I read I can do `calc: 3 + 5`, but I want this to happen automatically when I do `3 + 5`, how can I do this?

If this matters, I disabled the thing that searches the internet for everything I search on `Dash`.

Thanks.

Comment: You did `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa` then 
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-lens-utilities unity-scope-calculator`?

Comment: @Tim Yes, it says: `E: Unable to locate package unity-lens-utilities`, I think that might be the problem...

Comment: What version of ubuntu?

Comment: @Tim Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be because the Home lens doesn't search the "info" group of scopes by default, which include the calculator scope.

To enable follow the steps linked below and add 'info.scope' to the always-search list.

[How to change default "Categories" and "Sources" in Unity Dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385452/how-to-change-default-categories-and-sources-in-unity-dash)

Answer (score 3):

Type

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-calculator
```

You will get a message saying it is already installed.

In order for the results of calculations to show up, you have to filter the results to calculations, located at far right in filters. Worked for me.

Comment: It's a good start, but I would like that to happen every time, so I don't have to turn on that filter for every small calculation I do.