# Why does unity keep disabling search scopes?

Tags: unity, scopes

I use Unity to open my Virtualbox machine, but every time I search for the machine, I have to enable the Virtualbox scope. Why?

Comment: Which release you are using?

Comment: It's a shame that you put a bounty on what is essentially a duplicate question. Your answer is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/385452/how-to-change-default-categories-and-sources-in-unity-dash)

Comment: The answer didn't work, I added 'virtualbox.scope' and it is still not searched. I can't believe that custom scopes are this broken.